# Why the list comprehension variable is accessible after the operation is done?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

As part of another experience i encountered a problem in the list comprehension. In order to put simply,  if I  am trying the following code:

```
m = [ k**2 for k in range(7)]
print m
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
print k
6
```

1. My question is how is it python is able to get the value of k, outside the list comprehension?
2. Why is k not garbage collected?
3. Is this not a memory leak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not a memory leak as that term is usually defined. In Python 2.x, a list comprehension is not a separate scope, so a variable you use in a list comprehension is in the scope of the function that contains it. You can easily see this in action by setting `k` *before* the list comprehension; the listcomp will clobber it.

Because a valid reference exists, the object `k` points to is (properly) not garbage collected.

In Python 3.x, this was changed; all comprehensions create their own scopes and do not "leak" into the enclosing scope.

In Python 2.x, generator expressions *do* have their own scope, however, so if you want that behavior, just write it like this:

```
m = list(k**2 for k in range(7))
```

Comment: The problem is that if you have earlier declared the variable k & want to use it after list comprehension, the value of k gets changed.

Answer (score 11):

Because in Python 2, the list variable 'leaks' to the surrounding scope. This was a mistake in the way list comprehensions were built.

This has been corrected for dict and set comprehensions, generator expressions and in Python 3 for list comprehensions as well.

It is not a memory leak. It's just an error in the scope of the variable.

Comment: This isn't actually a mistake. The idea was that it should behave the same as the equivalent `for` loop. `for` loops don't have their own scope, so neither do list comprehensions. They changed their mind later.

Comment: The conclusion was that the decision to have them behave like `for` loops was the mistake :-) It turned out to be confusing people, and the behaviour was altered.