# Python weird behavior in list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7

```
def nrooks(n):
    #make board
    print n # prints 4
    arr = [0 for n in range(n)] # if 0 for n becomes 0 for x, it works fine
    print n # prints 3 instead of 4

nrooks(4)
```

How come the second `n` becomes `3` , different from the given parameter?

Comment: alternatively [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848082/why-do-list-comprehensions-write-to-the-loop-variable-but-generators-dont)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Python 2**

The `n` variable used in the list comprehension is the same `n` as is passed in.

The comprehension sets it to `1`, `2`, and then finally `3`.

Instead, change it to

```
arr = [0 for _ in range(n)]
```

or (surprisingly!)

```
arr = list(0 for n in range(n))
```

**Python 3**

**This has been fixed.**

[From the BDFL himself](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html):

> We also made another change in Python 3, to improve equivalence
>   between list comprehensions and generator expressions. In Python 2,
>   the list comprehension "leaks" the loop control variable into the
>   surrounding scope:

```
x = 'before'
a = [x for x in 1, 2, 3]
print x # this prints '3', not 'before'
```

> This was an artifact of the original implementation of list
>   comprehensions; it was one of Python's "dirty little secrets" for
>   years. It started out as an intentional compromise to make list
>   comprehensions blindingly fast, and while it was not a common pitfall
>   for beginners, it definitely stung people occasionally. For generator
>   expressions we could not do this. Generator expressions are
>   implemented using generators, whose execution requires a separate
>   execution frame...
>
> However, in Python 3, we decided to fix the "dirty little secret" of
>   list comprehensions by using the same implementation strategy as for
>   generator expressions. Thus, in Python 3, the above example (after
>   modification to use print(x) :-) will print 'before'.