# Get matched sublist from list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-2.x

```
cache = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
val = 'a'
if val in [x for [x,y] in cache]:
    print(y)
else:
    print('Not found')
```

In the above code, I wish to have `b` returned as the answer. However, the result is `d`. How can I retrieve the matched item from this expression? Pardon me if my terminology is incorrect, I just started learning Python and list comprehensions. I prefer to use this shorthand notation as I'm not comfortably familiar with lambda expressions just yet. Another curiosity, why is the result `d`?

Comment: This doesn't work as the list comprehension will be evaluated first before the loop.

Comment: Why "b"? Can you please explain your logic?

Comment: I'm finding if `a` exists within the `cache`. If it does, then I want to retrieve the corresponding sublist item that `a` is in.

Comment: Do you only want to filter on the first item of each sublist and return the second item? Or do you want to filter on *any* item of each sublist and return the full sublist then?

Comment: What is the expected result for ```val = 'a'; cache = ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']```

Comment: I want to filter on the first item and return the second item, i.e. the expected result for the code by @wwii code will be `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the the expression `[x for [x,y] in cache]` is valued as `['a','c']` before you look for `a` in it. and therefore, `a` is not related to `b` in it.

`y` contains the value of `d` because it the last value the was stored in `y` while iterating over `cache`

I think what you want is something like this:

```
cache = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
val = 'a'
ys = [y for [x,y] in cache if val == x]
if ys:
    print(ys[0])
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[x for [x, y] in cache]
```

This will create a temporary list `['a', 'c']` which you use to check whether `val` is contained in it. The list however is never kept around, so you can’t really access it. Since this is Python 2, the variables from within the list comprehension (`x` and `y`) actually leak out of the expression, so they are still around afterwards. But as you looped through `cache` they will have the last values which are `'c'` and `'d'` respectively.

```
>>> [x for [x, y] in cache]
['a', 'c']
>>> x, y
('c', 'd')
```

Of course that’s not really helpful, and the [variable leaking has been fixed in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19848168/216074) (where both variables stay undefined after the list comprehension).

But to solve your problem, what you want to do, is to look up the `x` from your cache, and then return the respective `y`. You can do this simply by creating a dictionary that maps `x` to `y`:

```
>>> d = {x: y for x, y in cache}
>>> d
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
>>> if val in d:
        print(d[val])
    else:
        print('Not found')

b
```

If you cache always contains sublists of two elements where the first one is used to look up things, then it’s a good idea to completely switch over to dictionaries. That way, you can have the lookup in constant time (which is very useful since you want a cache to be fast), and have a lot more control over it (like avoiding duplicate/old values).

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the list comprehension.

```
[y for x,y in cache if x == val]
```

Comment: Doesn’t work for a cache `[['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']]`.

Comment: @poke, what is the expected behavior if `val` is in multiple sublists?

Comment: The way I understood it, the filter should only work on the first value of the sublist, so only `'c'` should be returned in that case.

Comment: @poke - no spec then just an assumption.

Comment: You were right though, it was just an assumption, I could have easily been wrong here too :D