# List comprehensions leak their loop variable in Python2: how making it be compatible with Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, list-comprehension, compatibility

I just learnt from [Why do list comprehensions write to the loop variable, but generators don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848082/why-do-list-comprehensions-write-to-the-loop-variable-but-generators-dont) that **List comprehensions also "leak" their loop variable into the surrounding scope**.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
>>> x = 'before'
>>> a = [x for x in (1, 2, 3)]
>>> x
3
```

This bug is fixed in Python3.

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
>>> x = 'before'
>>> a = [x for x in (1, 2, 3)]
>>> x
'before'
```

What is the best way to make Python2 be compatible with Python3 at this point?

Comment: Don't rely on the name "leaking" ... Use unique names for your list-comp variables.

Comment: Use a generator expression with list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is usually to just not reuse variable names like that, but if you want something that gets the Python 3 behavior in both 2 and 3:

```
list(x for x in (1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

@mgilson's comment is probably the truth, but if you want to write code that works in both python2 and python3, you could wrap a generator function in a list function, Example:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
>>> x = 'before'
>>> a = list(x for x in (1, 2, 3))
>>> x
'before'
```

Comment: This is not the same

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Can you elaborate?

Comment: When I run your code in Python 2.7.11, `a` becomes `[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000009744900>]`, not the desired list.

Comment: Ahh, I see, it is an generator. Fixed

Comment: Access the first/only element of the list